# Invalid memory access of location Java - AWT-AppKit Thread - launching Web Application

Tags: java, web-applications, java-6

my configuration:

- Mac OS X 10.8.4
- Processor 2.4 GHz Intel Core i7
- Memory 8GB
- JDK 1.6.0_38-b04-436.jdk

I think, but I am not sure, this error started to show up after a App Store Java Update...

When I launch my web application, I keep getting this error:

```
2013-07-09 14:13:41.831 java[588:707] NSSoftLinking - The Librarian framework's library couldn't be loaded from (null).
2013-07-09 14:13:41.832 java[588:707] NSSoftLinking - The function 'LBCurrentProcessHasUbiquityContainer' can't be found in the Librarian framework.
Invalid memory access of location 0x38 rip=0x7fff9115e284
```

Also, the problem reported show up with some content:

```
... quit unexpectedly while using the Java plug-in.

The report will be send to Apple automatically.

Process:         java [3237]
Path:            /usr/bin/java
Identifier:      com.apple.javajdk16.cmd
Version:         1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [3236]
User ID:         3443

PlugIn Path:       /Library/Java/Home/bin/java
PlugIn Identifier: java
PlugIn Version:    1.0 (1.0)

Java information:

Exception type:
Bus Error (0xa) at pc=7fff9115e284
...

related thread:


JavaThread "AWT-AppKit" daemon
```

- I tried a different version of my web server, Tomcat 5, Tomcat 6.
- I tried resting the PRAM memory. http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379
- I tried installing the JavaForOSX2013-004. http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

Did not solve the problem.

Anybody has a clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted all Java directories in my Mac and install a previous version of Java and it is working again.

edit: JavaForOSX2013-003

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by installing [the latest jdk 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) and then pointing to it in catalina.sh :

JRE_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home"